# Probability of selecting at least 1 blue ball selected from at least 1 bowl

Tags: probability

Suppose there are $n$ bowls, such that each bowl contains $6$ blue balls and $5$ black balls. James selects $x$ balls at random with replacement from each bowl. Calculate the probability that at least one blue ball is selected from at least one bowl.

Hint: Your answer should be a function of $n$ and $x$.

My attempt:

$P(\text{ at least 1 blue ball selected from at least 1 bowl })
=1-P(\text{ selecting all black balls x time })
= 1- \biggl(P(\text{ selecting a random bowl })P(\text{ selecting a black ball })\biggr)^x
=1 - \biggl(\frac{5}{n(11)}\biggr)^x$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to claculate the complement probability of extracting **all Black Balls**.

From the first bowl this probability is

$$\left(\frac{5}{11} \right)^x$$

this must occur in any of the $n$ bowls, thus the requested probability is

$$1-\left(\frac{5}{11} \right)^{nx}$$